# ASP.NET 2.0 Web API with 2 parameters problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I wrote the following code to get a web api that accepts two parameters:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EventsController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/events/5
    [Route("api/[controller]/{deviceId}/{action}")]
    [HttpGet("{deviceId}/{action}")]
    public IEnumerable<CosmosDBEvents> Get(string deviceId,string action)
    {
        try
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I try to invoke it with the following url:

```
https://localhost:44340/api/events/abcde/indice
```

but it does not work. The error is 404 , Page not found.

I also changed the code as shown below but nothing changes :

```
[Route("~/api/events/{deviceId}/{action}")]
[HttpGet("{deviceId}/{action}")]
public IEnumerable<CosmosDBEvents> Get(string deviceId,string action)
{
    try
    {
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using ASP.NET Core routing, there are a few [Reserved routing names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#reserved-routing-names). Here's the list:

> - action
> - area
> - controller
> - handler
> - page

As you can see, `action` is on the list, which means you cannot use it for your own purposes. If you change `action` to something else that's not on the list, it will work:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EventsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{deviceId}/{deviceAction}")]
    public IEnumerable<CosmosDBEvents> Get(string deviceId, string deviceAction)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that I've also removed the `[Route(...)]` attribute from `Get`, which was redundant due to your use of the `[HttpGet(...)]` attribute that also specifies the route.